# Firebase Facebook AUTH - Login with Native App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

I'm currently handling the sign-in flow in my app with the Firebase SDK.
Provider: Facebook.

According to the firebase docs (or from what I could find), there are a couple of methods to redirect the user to Facebook. I'm currently using `signInWithPopup`, which works very fine, on the browser... On a mobile device is not that nice tho.

That's why I'm wondering if there is an option to do the sign-in flow using the **Facebook Native App** (if present) when the user is using a mobile device.

Is there any firebase.auth configuration or "hidden" method? 
Or does anyone know a work around?

Thanks in advance!

Techstack: Firebase + ReactJS

Comment: [This](https://codeburst.io/react-native-app-with-facebook-sdk-login-and-firebase-storage-606744701207) might be of be interest to you.

Comment: @Colin unfortunately thats for react native. Im using reactjs and firabase in a web app.

Comment: Oh sorry, [this](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web-react) link has everything you need.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're using a web app on mobile and want to open the Facebook mobile app, is that right?

Comment: Yes, exactly that! Do the facebook-login flow in the native app and not in the browser. Unfortunately, the repository you linked has only web-redirection alternatives.

Comment: I think you'd need to detect that the user is on mobile, and then deep link to a particular app I imagine. I don't have any code examples, but those are the topics that I'd Google!